# How to add max width media to Safari CSS media query

Tags: html, css, ios

This is my CSS media query code to show only on Safari/iOS.
I need to make it work only on `max-width` but it does not work when I added in row.
Please have any ideas?

```
@media not all and (min-resolution:.001dpcm) { 
  @media  {
    //my styles
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add media css like this:

```
@media not all and (min-resolution:.001dpcm) { 
  @media  (max-width: 767px) {
    div {
      background: red;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i have checked in safari and it's work perfactly

Comment: on my virtual machine on safari it does not work

Comment: @MinalChauhan you are missing a semicolon in your code

Comment: @DeniJ. have any ideas why it does not work?